# Laravel views not displaying

Tags: php, laravel

So apologies in advance for whatever rookie error I've made but I'm attempting to get my first Laravel project up and running, and I can't get a single view to display. Every view gives me an object not found (error 404) and I've searched every corner of the internet for some help but cannot find a single solution that works for me.

I'm building the project using PhpStorm on Mac OSX 11.6 running PHP 5.6.31 and Laravel 5.4.30, and hosting using Apache via XAMPP.

Also I cannot update composer as I get Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found, not sure if that's relevant but I believe it might be.

#### Routes

web.php:

```
<?php

Route::resource('issues', 'IssueController');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

api.php:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('issues', 'IssueController@index');
Route::get('issues/{id}', 'IssueController@show');
Route::post('issues', 'IssueController@store');
Route::put('issues/{id}', 'IssueController@update');
Route::delete('issues/{id}', 'IssueController@delete');

Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Comment: *I can't get a single view to display*, i know this is random, but please post your `routes.php` and the related controller? we can't magically figure out your troubles.

Comment: Html and Forms are not included to laravel you need to use them externally check this https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html

Comment: please update your question with `routes.php` and `app.php`

Comment: @BagusTesa there is no routes.php file are you referring to the php files inside the routes folder?

Comment: yes, the one that defines the routes.. i haven't coded in laravel since ages ago.. well, i just skims through your question and saw *error 404*. Looking at the next part of question, *Also I cannot update composer as I get Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'*, seems two different issue.. so random. but it worth the clue. you can follow Anar's suggestion for your second issue. but for the first one (404 error), please post the routes..

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have only one **web** route `http://example.com/`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

This is referring to a file in `/resources/views/welcome.blade.php`

Any other request like `http://example.com/page` do not exist therefor you get a 404 error.

Just add a new route like

```
Route::get('/page', function () {
    return view('page');
});
```

and creating a new **web** page `/resources/views/page.blade.php`

You also have **api** Routes like `http://example.com/api/issues` or `http://example.com/api/issues/id`

The Controller for those  Routes is called `IssueController` ans is usually in
`/app/Http/Controllers/IssueController.php` or `/app/Http/Controllers/Api/IssueController.php` there you should have methods like `index`, `store`, `show`, etc. here you have to decide what you like to do it a request is coming in.

Comment: The welcome page gives me the same object not found error unfortunately. In views I have a folder issues that contains create.blade.php which is what I am trying to call. I tried adding it to web.php in the manner you indicated but to no avail.

Comment: than just do `return view('issues.create');`

Comment: same error. is it possible that the problem is in my laptops configuration? the path or something similar?

Comment: please check your log files in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Not sure what I'm looking for but there is this error which is the same as when i run composer update (or install)

local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/assignment2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:208
Stack